# Duda lectura fichero en C

Tags: c

Buenas, mi pregunta es la siguiente. Tengo un fichero plano llamado group, en el que se muestran todos los usuarios de linux. Mi problema es que necesito leer cada una de las lineas del fichero y mostrar por pantalla el identificador del grupo y su nombre. Algo asi:

Nombre del grupo: root
Identificador del grupo: 0

Mi problema es que al recorrer el fichero con fscanf me guarda en la primera cadena toda la linea del fichero.
¿Alguien sabe como podría recorrer esa linea separando cada uno de los elementos de la linea?
Lineas del fichero:

```
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:syslog,rafa
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
```

El código:

```
char *valor="/etc/group";

fich=fopen(valor,"r");

if (fich)
{   
while ((fscanf(fich,"%s'%s'%d':'\n",nombre,basura3,&ident)!=0) && (fscanf(fich,"%s'%s'%d':'%s \n",nombre,basura3,&ident,basura)!=0) && (!feof(fich)))
    {
    printf("Nombre del grupo:%s \n",nombre );
    printf("Identificador del grupo: %d \n",ident);
    }
    fclose(fich);
}
else
{
printf("Error fichero.\n");
}
```

Comment: FYI: POSIX especifica las funciones `getgrent()` y asociadas (`setgrent()`, `endgrent()`, `getgrnam()`, `getgrgid()`) para leer la base de datos de grupos, que tradicionalmente se encuentra en `/etc/group`.

Answer (score 2):

No estás utilizando `fscanf` correctamente:

1. No necesitas declarar una variable para almacenar basura, `%*` hace que la función ignore esos carácteres.
2. Comparar el resultado con `0` no garantiza que se hayan asignado los valores a todas las variables, siempre compara con el número de variables que esperas rellenar, en este caso 2 ya que hemos decidido descartar la basura.
3. En un intento desesperado intentas meter con calzador `feof`, pero no pinta nada en este asunto :)

`fscanf` permite el uso de comodines: `%[^:]` (donde los dos puntos son el delimitador que estás usando en tu ejemplo)

Prueba:

```
while (fscanf(fich, "%[^:]:%*[^:]:%d%*[^\n]", nombre, &ident) == 2) {
```

Si la cadena siempre va a contener un sólo carácter entre los delimitadores `:x:`, puedes simplificarlo así:

```
while (fscanf(fich, "%[^:]:%*c:%d%*[^\n]", nombre, &ident) == 2) {
```

`%*c` consume (ignora) el carácter `x` mientras que `%*[^\n]` consume los carácteres sobrantes hasta llegar al salto de línea.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `strtok`:

```
char cad[20];
strcpy(cad,"adm:x:4:syslog,rafa");

const char* nombre;
const char* identStr;
const char* usuarios;
int ident;

nombre = strtok(cad,":");
strtok(NULL,":");
identStr = strtok(NULL,":");
usuarios = strtok(NULL,"\0");

sscanf(identStr,"%d",&ident);

printf("usuario: %s\nident: %d\nusuarios: %s\n",nombre,ident,usuarios);
```

Si luego necesitas separar los usuarios puedes repetir el proceso de `strtok` con el puntero `usuarios`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto, usamos `malloc` y `fseek`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *archivo = fopen("test.c", "r"); // declaramos el archivo a leer como (r) read
    if (archivo == NULL) {
        return 0; // si la lectura es nula, sale del script
    }
    char *final; // declaramos un valor como apuntador
    size_t n = 0; // se entiende jaja
    int c;
    fseek(archivo, 0, SEEK_END); // activamos el indicador de la posición al final
    long f_size = ftell(archivo);
    fseek(archivo, 0, SEEK_SET); // obtenemos el valor del indicador para steam
    final = malloc(f_size + 1); // en este caso es necesario usar malloc, será mejor
    while ((c = fgetc(archivo)) != EOF) {
        final[n++] = c; // metemos caracter por caracter en los bloques de memoria
    }
    final[n] = '\0'; // eliminamos el último salto de linea
    fclose(archivo); // cerramos el fichero
    printf("%s", final);
    free(final); // y liberamos el malloc
}
```

Comment: Le dijiste cómo leer un archivo a memoria (al nivel más bajo posible) pero nada de los delimitadores, que es lo que le complicaba el tema

Comment: es de fácl entendimiento, en pocas palabras, hacemos una variable, y le metemos caracter por caracter del archivo.